# How to get the HTML of the specific div in php?

Tags: php, curl, dom, screen-scraping

I'm a newbie to PHP scraping so please pardon me if I made any silly mistake.
I'm trying to scrape jobs from indeed. I'm getting the HTML through curl and then parsing it using DOM. Now the problem is that I want to get a div with its class name but that is inside the table's row. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Please help.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($result); 
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$obj = $dom->getElementById('resultsBody');
if (!empty($obj)) {
    $obj = $obj->getElementsByTagName('div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard"]');
    $ob= $obj->item(0);
    print $ob->nodeValue;
    print_r($obj);
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}
exit;
```

Also can we get the specific div along with its HTML and save in a variable to further get div's inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find from XPath.

```
$classname="your-class";
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. Also can we get the whole HTML with tags like in python?

Comment: Yes, full DOM can queried this way.

Comment: but I'm not getting it like <div>Hello </div> . Also css and js functions are also there.